# How to connect to database on remote server

Tags: database, sql-server, vpn

Where there is VPN to remote server and then access to the database via local network interface, **how can one establish a remote link between one's computer (with a programme such as Visual Studio 2010) and SQL Server (e.g. 2008 R2)** ?

Any attempts to create a direct link to the SQL Server are blocked. Whilst the SQL Server *can* be configured to allow external access, this provides its own host of problems.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the VPN is between the client machine and the SQL server directly?

Answer (score 1):

If the VPN is between you and the SQL server, you may need to add users with permissions on the SQL server allowing remote access for them originating from your VPN servers IP.